# How do I find out what display resolution I SHOULD use? (using virtualbox)

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, display, display-resolution

I just set up Ubuntu 20.04.1 with VirtualBox 6.1 and the standard screen resolution sizes don't allow for me to use my full monitor display.
I know how to use `xrandr` to add new resolution ratios to my options, but I don't know which resolution ratio I SHOULD be using. At this point, I've added 10 or so different resolutions (eg. 1440x720, 1920x1080, ...) but I can't find the one that perfectly fits.

Is there a way to find the exact resolution ratio or exact values for my display?
I'm getting a bit tired of trial and error at this point.

In case it's important, this is how I'm adding custom resolutions in terminal:

```
cvt 1440 720
sudo xrandr --newmode "1440x720_60.00" 83.75 ...
sudo xrandr --addmode Virtual1 "1440x720_60.00"
```

Comment: If you install **Guest Additions** (on the guest VM, of course), then the display will automatically fill in whatever window size - including full-screen - that you're using.

Comment: Perfect, this worked. Thanks!